# value stored in memory, accesed with cheat engine at run time gives unknown value such as fmul dword ptr [edx+4F]

Tags: c++, windows, memory

i was just playing around with some C++, and i wanted to inspect the memory adress that stored my variables value, i used cheat engine to inspect the value at runtime, and what i got at the adress was:

```
opcode(fmul): fmul dword ptr [edx+4F]

the next 2 adresses in memory are

opcode(add): [esi+67],ah
opcode(add): cl
enter code here
```

what does this mean, and how is it translated to the end value (which is a string (fgfg)) ?

Comment: This looks a lot like you may be looking at data that was never intended to execute, and disassembling it anyway. Unless you're sure what you're looking at it real code, the result from disassembling may be entirely meaningless.

Comment: Running a simple C++ program that assigns a string value to a variable, running in c++ debugger

Comment: Jerry is right, you're trying to view data as code. `add [esi+67h], ah` converts to `00 66 67`, which when viewed as ASCII is `\0fg`, or the starting point of your target string.

Comment: How did you translate add [esi+67h], ah to 00 66 67 ?

Comment: https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly , only trick is to use `esi+0x67` instead of `esi+67h`. What source are you compiling, what compiler/debugger are you using?

Comment: c++ and visual studio 2010